# what is the mean of zero plus point '0.' appeared in user-defined function

Tags: pine-script

I am new to pine script. when i analyse the pine scripts which has been published. I am confused.
what is the role of "0." on the last line of following function:

```
update_zigzag(value, bindex)=>
    if array.size(zigzag) == 0
        add_to_zigzag(value, bindex)
    else
        if (dir == 1 and value > array.get(zigzag, 0)) or (dir == -1 and value < array.get(zigzag, 0))
            array.set(zigzag, 0, value)
            array.set(zigzag, 1, bindex)
        0.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is used as return value (`0.` is the same as float `0.0`) of the function `update_zigzag()`.
While `array.set` returns `void`, `add_to_zigzag` probably returns some `float` value. So that way in `if else` statement there will be some result value.
This construct is not necessary.